# pipe "less" content out, when "less" get content from stdin

Tags: vim, ipython, less-unix

In "ipython", we use `some_obj??` to get documentation, which uses "less" to show the docs.  How can we get the document out of "less", into a text editor?  The content is fed from stdin, so pressing "v" gives the error: "can not edit standard input"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`some_obj??` is equivalent  the built-in `help` function. This is a wrapper around pydoc.help.

```
import pydoc
doc = pydoc.text.document(some_obj)
print doc
```

You may save the documentation to a file. Then open in a text editor.